# Laravel 6: can set boolean to 1 but not to zero

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

So basically I have a favorited value for my tasks. It's named 'favorited' and has a boolean so 1/true or 0/false. (mySQL)

Currently, each row (a task) has a font awesome star, if favorited is 1, it will become fas with text gold so it'll show a gold star. If favorited is 0, it will become far, which makes it a white star with the inside empty.

`<a href="#" class="del_link text-white"><i class="{{ $task->favorited ? 'text-gold fas' : 'far' }} fa-star"></i></a>`

It has class `del_link` which triggers a javaScript/jQuery function.  Which submits the `<a>` parent form

```
$('.del_link').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(event){
        $(this).parent().submit();
    });
});
```

Now this is the form wrapped around the `<a></a>`

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('tasks.update', $task) }}">
    @csrf @method('patch')
    <input type="hidden" name="favorited" value="{{ $task->favorited ? 0 : 1 }}">
    <a href="#" class="del_link text-white"><i class="{{ $task->favorited ? 'text-gold fas' : 'far' }} fa-star"></i></a>
</form>
```

So basically, if favorited === 1, then set the favorited value to 0, so when I submit the form, I set the favorited value to 0. Now this for some reason doesn't work. Whenever I press the star so I can favorite it, it works, but when I do it the other way around to unfavorite; it doesn't.

This is my code for the `TaskController.php`

```
public function update(Request $request, Task $task)
{
    $task->update([
       'favorited' => request()->has('favorited')
    ]);

    return back();
}
```

Actually, the code above and the method is something I got from the Laravel 5.8 scratch video. (Laracasts laravel tutorial)

It has worked for me using a checkbox instead of using a star, but it doesnt work this way.

I've tried using a lengthy if statement, that if request was 1 I would set it to 1. (request = 1 means that the hidden input was 1 so it wasn't favorited) and an else, so if 0, it would set it to 0 thereby unfavoriting it.

But in that case, it still didnt work. I've dd the request, task and text to show me where I am and what I get, but to no avail.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `request()->has('favorited')`, it return `true` when the request contain the input `favorited=1` or `favorited=0` (both cases).

It does work with a checkbox because when an input `type="checkbox"` is unchecked, it is not send in the request.

When it's an input `type="hidden"`, `favorited` will be present in the request all the time.

You should change it to `'favorited' => (int)(bool)request()->input('favorited')`

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me. Also, favorited should be present, since thats the only thing the form is sending. A 1 or a 0.

Comment: This just nicely opens the door to inspect the element and put like any number, isn't it?

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović yeah, but since it's used like a boolean, it doesn't matter. it's either `=0` or `!=0`. and since the value is cast to an integer, there is no real threat. you can also force cast into `1` or `0`, `+(bool)$request->input('favorited')`

Comment: My question if you know (i am lazy to try it): Will it crash if you set the column to boolean and try to save for example 2 (inspect element) ??

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović if the database field is set to boolean, you can't even save the value `1` or `0`. 
MySQL is not PHP

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests) `$request->has('favorited')` checks if `favorited` is present in the request. Whether it's set to 0, 1, or any other value does not impact the returned value.

Instead, using `(bool)$request->input('favorited')` should work. Or if you haven't cast the `favorited` attribute to a boolean `(bool)$request->input('favorited') ? 1 : 0`.

If this doesn't work, the value isn't set properly in the request, so it's most likely a front-end issue. In that case, `dd($request->input('favorited'))` to see if the value is present as expected. I don't immediately see an issue with your view and js.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, also that was it, it would check if it was present, not if it was either 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Your problem is on both, frontend and backend:

1. Backend: request()->has('field');
   The request will always have this field which means the value of it is *1* all the time since you have input field presented.
2. Frontend: You are not changing the value of the input.

Two fixes for this:
1. Frontend you can set Javascript to change the input value when you press this to the opposite.

2. Do the same as #1 on the backend, which is easier.

So, this should work for you:

```php
// First validate you have that field.
request()->validate([
    'favorited' => ['required'],
]);

// Then set the favorited to opposite of current.
$task->update([
   'favorited' => !$task->favorited // notice the "!" (take oposite value)
]);
```

Edit:
By the way you can get rid of Javascript by removing input hidden and making submit the value you want to use, since its either 0 or 1.

So: remove the input type="hidden", and change from a-href to button.

```html
<button name="favorited">
    <i class="{{ $task->favorited ? 'text-gold fas' : 'far' }} fa-star"></i>
</button>
```

That should do the thing.

Comment: For the frontend it does work, when inspected it still shows me the value 1 if its not favorited and the opposite as well. die dumping the request has shown me that I am sending the proper boolean value when I submit it.